# MsAccess MsgBox to pull last record as a string

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am trying to create a button that will show the user the last lot, product code and qty that was saved to the database.

I am not sure how to write this in VBA, in other languages there are ways to view the last record by the method `Bottom` or `Max`.

I am trying to pull the data from column `Product` where the `User` column is equal to `Environ("USERNAME")` and the `ID` column has its max value.

Table to pull from is `Data_Log`.

Been looking around, but just no luck yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
Private Sub cmdShowLastData_Click()
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select * from Data_Log where [User]='" & _
        Environ("USERNAME") & "' and [ID]=" & DMax("ID", "Data_Log", "[User]='" & Environ("USERNAME") & "'"))

    MsgBox "Last product: " & rst!Product & vbCrLf & _
           "Last product code: " & rst!ProductCode & vbCrLf & _
           "Last product qty: " & rst!Qty

    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: So I added a new column to the table and now this doesn't pull the info from the new column. Any ideas how to make it pull the new data?

Comment: Did you add to the message data from new column `rst!MyNewColumn`?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to Sergeys solution, using `TOP 1`:

```
strSql = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Data_Log WHERE [User]='" & Environ("USERNAME") & "' " & _
         "ORDER BY ID DESC"
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSql)
```

The rest is the same.